# Display my foursquare checkins on a LCD screen using Raspberry PI.Suggest which foursquare api should I use to fetch data about my check in's

Tags: api, rest, raspberry-pi, foursquare, arduino-uno

Want to display my recent 5 check in on a LCD screen using raspberry pi. I am newbee in web development. Could any one please help me to know which foursquare restful service will be use full for this project. Is their any push restful api available ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this endpoint: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins

To get your own 5 most recent check-ins, your http request will be something like:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?limit=5&sort=newestfirst&oauth_token=XXXXX&v=20140328

Comment: Try it out here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/self/checkins%3Flimit%3D5%26sort%3Dnewestfirst